# No rule to make target in rule build_veins

Tags: snakemake, veins, sumo

I am trying to use the serpentine [serpentine](https://github.com/tkn-tub/serpentine-env) scenario following [this](https://github.com/tkn-tub/serpentine-env/blob/master/examples/Tutorial_Using_the_Serpentine_Scenario.ipynb) tutorial.

When I run `snakemake -jall` I get the following error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 4
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job                count
---------------  -------
all                    1
build                  2
build_veins            2
build_veins_vlc        2
total                  7

Select jobs to execute...

[Mon Nov 20 11:16:38 2023]
rule build_veins:
    input: lib/veins/src/Makefile
    output: lib/veins/src/libveins.so
    jobid: 9
    reason: Missing output files: lib/veins/src/libveins.so
    wildcards: dbg=
    threads: 4
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/qx/8mj8c3js6zdfblrg8s_5rqtr0000gn/T

[Mon Nov 20 11:16:38 2023]
Error in rule build_veins:
    jobid: 9
    input: lib/veins/src/Makefile
    output: lib/veins/src/libveins.so
    shell:
        make -j4 -C lib/veins/src MODE=release
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2023-11-20T111637.880905.snakemake.log
```

Can anyone help me?

I am using:
• sumo Version 1.18.0
• OMNeT Version 6.0.2
• libprotoc 25.0

Comment: In the directory where you execute snakemake, try to run `make -j4 -C lib/veins/src MODE=release` directly on the command line and post what happens.

Comment: Here is the output, `make: *** No rule to make target ../out/clang-release/src/veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.o', needed by ../out/clang-release/src/libveins.dylib'.  Stop.`